# NSPredicate matching string for Cloudkit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I need to pull the record from cloudkit matching a string.

I have a User record type, with an email field. I have multiple records with the same email, but I can't get the predicate to get me the records.

I've tried all of these:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "email = 'julio_ukohgsp_chevez@tfbnw.net'")
NSPredicate(format: "email == %@", argumentArray: [email])
NSPredicate(format: "email IN %@", [email])
NSPredicate(format: "email contains %@", email)
NSPredicate(format: "email = %@", email)
NSPredicate(format: "email == %@", email)
```

My query specifies the record type:

```
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "email == %@", email))
```

When I do a predicate with value: true, I get all records including the one I want.. I know for sure I have a User with that email, multiple in fact..

What am I missing?

Edit ..

```
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "email BEGINSWITH %@", email))
```

Does work and brings back records, but I want an exact match!

Comment: Does `LIKE` instead of `==` work?

Answer (score 7):

I had same issue and was able to resolve it by adding Queryable index on user field in my case. Note, after index was added I needed to write data again to CloudKit to be able to perform query.

Code for creation of  predicate:

```
let user = "test-user"
let userPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "user == %@", user)
```

Comment: MAKE IT QUERYABLE, this saved me.. I couldn't figure out why i couldn't filter by a predicate, once I made my property queryable I could use it to filter the cloud by a specific entity relationship. I thought I was unable to make tomany relationships for a while there.

Answer (score 3):

I've been having this same issue with one of my apps. In my case, I needed to subscribe to a list of predicates where a lot of search criteria needed to be met but the search or filter predicate gave me the most trouble. I also tried:

```
let word1 = "Mac"
    
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Title CONTAINS %@", word1)
```

This worked but only when 'word1' was a single word with no spaces and 'Title' was a 'String List' in the cloud.

The clarification that I have come across in all my research is:

You need to use the term 'self' when you create a predicate and what that does is it searches all the fields that are a searchable string. Here is the information I got from [Apple's Website.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckquery)

> Predicates support the following variable substitution strings:
>
> Use %@ for value objects such as strings, numbers, and dates.
>
> Use %K for the name of a field. This substitution variable indicates that the substituted string should be used to look up a field name.
>
> With one exception, the CONTAINS operator can be used only to test list membership. The exception is when you use it to perform full-text searches in conjunction with the self key path. The self key path causes the server to look in searchable string-based fields for the specified token string. For example, a predicate string of @"self contains 'blue'" searches for the word “blue” in all fields marked for inclusion in full-text searches. You cannot use the self key path to search in fields whose type is not a string.

What I ended up doing, which there has to be a better way, is my 'Title' property is still a 'String List' in the cloud and in my code I made an array of all the words in my searchTerm and with each word in the searchTerm I made a separate NSPredicate and I used those as part of a NSCompoundPredicate. I then added the NSCompoundPredicate to my subscription and it worked. Here is my example:

```
var searchCriteria: [NSPredicate] = []

for word in searchTerm {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self CONTAINS %@", word)
    searchCriteria.append(predicate)
}

let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "Price > %d", minPrice)

let p3 = NSPredicate(format: "Price < %d", maxPrice)

let p4 = NSPredicate(format: "Category == %d", category)

searchCriteria.append(p2)
searchCriteria.append(p3)
searchCriteria.append(p4)

let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: searchCriteria)
```

I hope this helps. There has to be a better way to do this and if anyone knows, please let me know cause I understand there isn't a lot of good explanations on how to do things with CloudKit.

Comment: Funny that you commented, because apple replied to my radar saying that the issue was fixed...But I have not been able to test it, since I'm not encoding my emails and haven't had the issue since.

Comment: That's interesting. Well if you end up testing it and it works for you, please let me know how you did it.