# CKQuery -Specific Field with Specific Value

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ckquery

How can I query for this field **myId** with this specific id **-MqXU-kKVhl5ef10XD**

post:

```
let database = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.myCo.myApp").publicCloudDatabase

let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Sample")

record["myId"] = "-MqXU-kKVhl5ef10XD"

database.save(record) { (ckRecord, error) in
})
```

query:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate()
    
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Sample", predicate: predicate)
    
database.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (ckRecords, error) in
    if let err = error { return }

    guard let records = ckRecords else { return }

    guard let record = records.first else { return }

    guard let myId = record.value(forKey: "myId") as? String else { return }
    print(myId)
})
```

Comment: found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47693400/4833705) from @vanjakom

Answer (score 0):

found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47693400/4833705) from @vanjakom. I had to make the **myId** field `Queryable`:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "myId == %@", "-MqXU-kKVhl5ef10XD")
```